# loading seer data into R

Tags: r, loading, read.table, fixed-width

I am trying to load SEER data from ASCII files. There is only a .sas load file which I am trying to convert into an R load command.

the .sas load file looks like this:

```
filename seer9 './yr1973_2015.seer9/*.TXT';                                           

data in;                                                                              
infile seer9 lrecl=362;                                                             
input                                                                               
@ 1   PUBCSNUM             $char8.  /* Patient ID */                              
@ 9   REG                  $char10. /* SEER registry */                           
@ 19  MAR_STAT             $char1.  /* Marital status at diagnosis */             
@ 20  RACE1V               $char2.  /* Race/ethnicity */                          
@ 23  NHIADE               $char1.  /* NHIA Derived Hisp Origin */                
@ 24  SEX                  $char1.  /* Sex */
```

I have the following code to try an replicate a similar loading process:

```
data <- read.table("OTHER.TXT", 
col.names = c("pubcsnum", "reg", "mar_stat", "race1v", "nhaide", "sex"),
sep = c(1, 9, 19, 20, 23, 24))
```

If I use the `sep`aregument I get the following error:

```
Error in read.table("OTHER.TXT", col.names = c("pubcsnum", "reg", "mar_stat",
:invalid 'sep' argument
```

If I dont use the `sep` argument I get the following error:

```
Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,
: 
  line 1 did not have 133 elements
```

Does anyone have experience loading seer data? Does anyone have a suggestion why this isn't working?

*of note when I use the `fill = TRUE` argument, the second error `line 1 did not have 133 elements` doesn't occur anymore, BUT the data is not correct when I evaluate the first few observations. I further confirmed by evaluating a known variable `sex` :

```
> summary(data$sex)
     Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
0.000e+00 2.000e+00 3.020e+03 7.852e+18 9.884e+13 2.055e+20
```

where the values are 1/2 and the summary is nonsensical

Comment: Can you add a `fill = TRUE` to the read.table command, `read.table` does not know how to handle missing values.

Comment: `fill = TRUE` gets rid of the error, but please see my edits above for more clarification. Sadly, the data comes out wonky.

Comment: While in SAS you have to specify where to start the column (e.g position 1,9 etc...)  you do not need to do that in your `sep` argument. `sep` is looking for the delimiter not the position of starting variables. See here for more details: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.4.3/topics/read.table

Comment: I had seen the method of using`sep` to define locations of data here: http://data.princeton.edu/R/readingData.html . Admittedly it isn't described in the documentation and doesn't seem to work. However, just loading the data seems to create values for variables that make no sense (as listed above). Any ideas if there is a better way to do this?

Comment: If you have SAS I think the best would be to create the file there, then use something like 'haven::read_sas()` to read in the file to your R session. For your sex variable it seems that either it is an error in reading in or SEER codes missing values with a very large number. That information should be in the code book (hopefully).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the other comments and answers point out most of this but here's a more complete answer for your exact problem. I have heard of many people struggling with these ASCII files (including many related but, not very simple packages) and I wanted to answer these for anyone else searching.

#### Fixed width files

These SEER "ASCII" files are actually fixed width text files (ASCII is an encoding standard not a file format). This means that there is no delimiter character (e.g. "," or "\t") that separates the fields (in a .csv or .tsv).

Instead, each field is defined by a start and end position in the line (sometimes a start position and the field width/length). This is what we see the in .sas file that you summarize:

```
input                                                                               
@ 1   PUBCSNUM             $char8.  /* Patient ID */                              
@ 9   REG                  $char10. /* SEER registry */  
...
```

#### What does this mean?

- the first Patient ID field starts at position **1** and has a length of **8** (from $char8, similar to precision in SQL schemas etc.) which means it ends at position **8**.
- the second field, SEER registry ID, starts at position **9** (1 + 8 from the previous field) and has a length of **10** (again from $char10) which means it ends at position **18**.
- etc.

Where the `@` number consistently increases so the fields don't overlap.

#### Reading fixed width files

I find the `readr::read_fwf()` function nice and simple, mostly because it has a couple of helper functions, namely `fwf_positions()` that tell it how to define each field by start and end (or widths, with `fwf_widths()`).

So, to read just these two fields from the file we can do:

```
read_fwf(<file>, fwf_positions(start=c(1, 9), end=c(8, 18), col_names=c("patient_id", "registry_id")))
```

Where col_names is only there to rename the columns.

#### Helper script.

I have struggled with these before so I actually wrote [some code](https://github.com/vincentmajor/SEER_read_fwf/blob/master/SEER_fixed_width_read.R) that reads that .sas file and extracts the start positions, widths, column names and descriptions.

Here is the entire thing, just replace the file name:

```
## Script to read the SEER file dictionary and use it to read SEER ASCII data files.

library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

#### Reading the file dictionary ----
## https://seer.cancer.gov/manuals/read.seer.research.nov2017.sas

sas.raw <- read_lines("https://seer.cancer.gov/manuals/read.seer.research.nov2017.sas")
sas.df <- tibble(raw = sas.raw) %>% 
  ## remove first few rows by insisting an @ that defines the start index of that field
  filter(str_detect(raw, "@")) %>% 
  ## extract out the start, width and column name+description fields
  mutate(start = str_replace(str_extract(raw, "@ [[:digit:]]{1,3}"), "@ ", ""),
         width = str_replace(str_extract(raw, "\\$char[[:digit:]]{1,2}"), "\\$char", ""),
         col_name = str_extract(raw, "[[:upper:]]+[[:upper:][:digit:][:punct:]]+"),
         col_desc = str_trim(str_replace(str_replace(str_extract(raw, "\\/\\*.+\\*\\/"), "\\/\\*", ""), "\\*\\/", "" )) ) %>% 
  ## coerce to integers
  mutate_at(vars(start, width), funs(as.integer)) %>% 
  ## calculate the end position
  mutate(end = start + width - 1)

column_mapping <- sas.df %>% 
  select(col_name, col_desc)

#### read the file with the start+end positions----

## CHANGE THIS LINE
file_path = "data/test_COLRECT.txt"

## read the file with the fixed width positions
data.df <- read_fwf(file_path, 
                    fwf_positions(sas.df$start, sas.df$end, sas.df$col_name))
## result is a tibble
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed width files such as those described by that .sas file are read with `read.fwf` function in the `foreign` package. I'm afraid that nicely formatted webpage hosted by Princeton is simply wrong about how to use `read.table` for this purpose. There are really no separators, just positions. In the case in point you could have used (assuming you have a directory named "yr1973_2015.seer9" in your working directory):

```
 library(utils)  #not really needed, just correcting my faulty memory 
 inputdf <- read.fwf( "yr1973_2015.seer9/OTHER.TXT",
                       widths= c(1, 9, 19, 20, 23, 24),
          col.names = c("pubcsnum", "reg", "mar_stat", "race1v", "nhaide", "sex"))
```

You would lose most of the information since the `lrecl` value tells us there are 362 characters per line, but this would be a good test case and you could then switch to the SAScii functions.... and thanks to @AnthonyDamico:

```
packageDescription("SAScii")
#---------------
Package: SAScii
Type: Package
Title: Import ASCII files directly into R using only a SAS
      input script
Version: 1.0
Date: 2012-08-18
Authors@R: person( "Anthony Joseph" , "Damico" , role = c(
      "aut" , "cre" ) , email = "ajdamico@gmail.com" )
Description: Using any importation code designed for SAS
      users to read ASCII files into sas7bdat files, the
      SAScii package parses through the INPUT block of a
      (.sas) syntax file to design the parameters needed
      for a read.fwf function call.  This allows the user
      to specify the location of the ASCII (often a .dat)
      file and the location of the .sas syntax file, and
      then load the data frame directly into R in just one
      step.
License: GPL (>= 2)
URL: https://github.com/ajdamico/SAScii
Depends: R (>= 2.14)
LazyLoad: Yes
Packaged: 2012-08-17 08:35:18 UTC; AnthonyD
Author: Anthony Joseph Damico [aut, cre]
Maintainer: Anthony Joseph Damico <ajdamico@gmail.com>
Repository: CRAN
Date/Publication: 2012-08-17 10:55:15
Built: R 3.4.0; ; 2017-04-20 18:55:31 UTC; unix

-- File: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/SAScii/Meta/package.rds
```

I wasn't abolutely sure that the trailing info would be effectively ignored on those long lines but checked with this slight mod of athe first example on the `?read.fwf` page:

```
> ff <- tempfile()
> cat(file = ff, "12345689", "98765489", sep = "\n")
> read.fwf(ff, widths = c(1,2,3))
  V1 V2  V3
1  1 23 456
2  9 87 654
>unlink(ff)
```

I checked my memory that using Anthony's name as a search term could be helpful and find that his website has been updated. Check out:

http://asdfree.com/surveillance-epidemiology-and-end-results-seer.html